# Multiple Single Chat Rooms using SignalR (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I've to create a Chat between two users (a hired person and a hirer). It doesn't need to be real-time but using SignalR I might accomplish that, but no problem.

I'll store the previous messages on a database to retrieve everytime the chat was open.

So, I need to broadcast a message only between two users, but, a user can have multiple chat rooms with differente people (but only 1:1).

How can I accomplish that logic in my code? Do I have to use Groups? And if so, how can I store the information that "this user has to send message to that user", on a 1:1 chat, and not broadcast to everyone?

My ChatHub class:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IChatAppService _chatAppService;

    public ChatHub(IChatAppService chatAppService)
    {
        _chatAppService = chatAppService;
    }

    public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(ChatAddVM message, string userName)
    {
        string connectionId = GetConnectionId();

        await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("broadcastMessage", userName, message.Message);
        //USED TO SAVE THE MESSAGE ON DB
        await _chatAppService.CreateMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question

> how can I store the information that "this user has to send message to
>   that user", on a 1:1 chat, and not broadcast to everyone?

I think you can store into db the information like from which user to which user had chat. Because you already store previous message between user with user so I think you can do the same like that

Also to send message between 1:1 I write small blog [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/05/01/send-message-to-specific-user-in-signalr/) so you can take a look at

The idea is every user have 1 connection id so we need to store the connection id of the user in the memory to send message from 1 to 1

Comment: Perfect! I'd accomplish this with my structure and ConnectionIds dictionary on the Hub. Thank you!